# Loading a .php file takes too much time?

Tags: php, webserver

On a project I've been working on, I have `temp2.php` file which is fetched on page load. When I refreshed the page, `temp2.php` seems not fetched by the server. I checked on `Firebug` on NET, and I saw that loading `temp2.php` file is on the process. That is why my charts(which is being processed on `temp2.php`) are not shown. I am confused with this bug/anomaly because this does not happen ALL THE TIME. I did not also notice when exactly this occurs. Is this because of a slow internet connection or this is something else?

Comment: It could be the webserver it is stored on has performance issues, or is on shared hosting with too many sites on it. It could also be something wrong with your code that is causing a bottleneck in processing whatever is going on in your script. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: Found it. I had an infinite loop. Darn! Thanks @Eric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the webserver it is stored on has performance issues, or is on shared hosting with too many sites on it. It could also be something wrong with your code that is causing a bottleneck in processing whatever is going on in your script. Some code would be helpful.

(figured I would post as answer to score some points...)